# Temperature of a Lennard-Jones system

Tags: c++, simulation, physics

Are the formulas used in getTemperature() and setTemperature() correct?

````
#ifndef LJ_HPP
#define LJ_HPP

#include <vector>

#include "common.hpp"
#include "vec3.hpp"

class LennardJones
{
public:
    real kB;
    real epsilon;
    real sigma;

public:
    LennardJones()
    {
        kB = 0;
        epsilon = 0;
        sigma = 0;
    }

    LennardJones(double epsilon, double sigma, real kB) : epsilon(epsilon), sigma(sigma), kB(kB) {}

    real getPotential(const Vec3& distance) const
    {
        real r_mag = std::sqrt(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z);
        real s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
        real s_over_r6 = pow(s_over_r, 6);
        return epsilon * (s_over_r6 * s_over_r6 - 2.0 * s_over_r6);
    }

    real getPotentialAttractive(const Vec3& distance) const
    {
        real r_mag = std::sqrt(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z);
        real s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
        real s_over_r6 = pow(s_over_r, 6);
        real attrPotential = (-2.0) * epsilon * s_over_r6;
        return attrPotential;
    }

    real getPotentialRepulsive(const Vec3& distance) const
    {
        real r_mag = std::sqrt(distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z);
        real s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
        real s_over_r12 = pow(s_over_r, 12);
        real repPotential = epsilon * s_over_r12;
        return repPotential;
    }

    Vec3 getForceApprox(const Vec3& distance) const
    {
        // Define a small distance for the derivative approximation
        real dr = 1e-6;
        Vec3 force;
        std::vector<Vec3> r_plus_dr = { distance, distance, distance };
        r_plus_dr[0].x += dr;
        r_plus_dr[1].y += dr;
        r_plus_dr[2].z += dr;

        // The force is the negative derivative of the potential energy
        force.x = -(getPotential(r_plus_dr[0]) - getPotential(distance)) / dr;
        force.y = -(getPotential(r_plus_dr[1]) - getPotential(distance)) / dr;
        force.z = -(getPotential(r_plus_dr[2]) - getPotential(distance)) / dr;
        return force;
    }

    Vec3 getAcceleration(const Vec3& distance, double mass) const
    {
        double rSquared = distance.x * distance.x + distance.y * distance.y + distance.z * distance.z;
        double r6 = std::pow(sigma * sigma / rSquared, 3);
        double r12 = r6 * r6;

        double magnitude = 24.0 * epsilon / mass * (2.0 * r12 - r6) / rSquared;

        Vec3 acceleration(distance.x * magnitude, distance.y * magnitude, distance.z * magnitude);
        return acceleration;
    }

    Vec3 getForce(Vec3 position) const
    {
        real r_mag = std::sqrt(position.x * position.x + position.y * position.y + position.z * position.z);
        real s_over_r = sigma / r_mag;
        real s_over_r6 = s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r * s_over_r;
        real s_over_r12 = s_over_r6 * s_over_r6;
        real factor = 24.0 * epsilon * (2.0 * s_over_r12 - s_over_r6) / (r_mag * r_mag * r_mag);

        Vec3 force;
        force.x = factor * position.x;
        force.y = factor * position.y;
        force.z = factor * position.z;
        return force;
    }

    real getKineticEnergy(real mass, const Vec3& velocity) const
    {
        real vx = velocity.x;
        real vy = velocity.y;
        real vz = velocity.z;
        return 0.5 * mass * (vx * vx + vy * vy + vz * vz);
    }

    real getTotalEnergy(real mass, const Vec3& distance, const Vec3& velocity) const
    {
        real potentialEnergy = getPotential(distance);
        real kineticEnergy = getKineticEnergy(mass, velocity);
        return potentialEnergy + kineticEnergy;
    }

    double getTemperature(real mass, const Vec3& velocity) const
    {       
        double kineticEnergy = getKineticEnergy(mass, velocity);
        double temperature = (2.0 * kineticEnergy) / (3.0 * kB);
        return temperature;
    }

    void setTemperature(Vec3& velocity, real currentTemperature, real targetTemperature) const
    {
        real scalingFactor = std::sqrt(targetTemperature / currentTemperature);
        velocity *= scalingFactor;
    }
};
#endif // !LJ_HPP
```
````

Comment: What's with `real`? Is that an alias for `float`, `double`, or something else?

Comment: @Reinderien, either float or double, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

What you call temperature in your code is not strictly a temperature. It instead is the kinetic energy contribution of an individual atom to the temperature of the whole system. This is only valid for an ideal gas, and a system using a Lennard-Jones potential already is no longer an ideal gas. But sure, if you only are interested in the kinetic temperature of individual atoms, then `getTemperature()` is correct.

The problem is in `setTemperature()`. The idea is that you apply this to all atoms in the system to get the system to the desired temperature. However, that doesn't result in a physically realistic distribution of the velocities. Consider that in an ideal gas, the velocities follow the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution), and you can't simply multiply velocities to get that distribution for a higher temperature. You will have something similar for your Lennard-Jones gas. It's fine if you [thermalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermalisation) the system right after using `setTemperature()`, but if you use this to heat or cool the system during the actual simulation, it will introduce discontinous jumps in the velocity of the particles, resulting in an unrealistic system. The solution is to use a more physically correct thermostat, such as the Gaussian thermostat mentioned in [Yanxiang Zhao's Brief introduction to the thermostats](https://home.gwu.edu/%7Eyxzhao/ResearchNotes/ResearchNote007Thermostat.pdf) referenced in this [Matter Modeling question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9922).

Consider that you are already using the more realistic Lennard-Jones potential instead of a naive hard sphere model, and you are using leapfrog integration instead of the naive [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method), then you also shouldn't use a naive thermostat.